# Getting func.call is not a function in React while trying to call a Node.js function. What's my problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

I have a Node.js function utilizing sockets on another React page which is working correctly removing users from a queue. I'm trying to implement that function on another page but I keep getting func.call is not a function.  Here's the problematic React:

```
class Stations extends Component {

static propTypes = {
className: PropTypes.string,
queue: PropTypes.array,
Remove: PropTypes.func,
}

Remove = (station, index) => {
   this.socket.on('removeUser', {station, index});
}

render() {
    const { className, queue } = this.props

return (
...
   <Button as={Label} color="red" className="deleteLabel" size="tiny" onClick="{this.Remove(station, index)}">Remove</Button>
...
```

Comment: Your `onClick` is a *string*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick` should be a function:

```
onClick={() => this.Remove(station, index)}
```

Additionally, if you meant to send a message over socket instead of adding a new event listener, you probably meant `emit`:

```
this.socket.emit('removeUser', {station, index});
```

Comment: Updated to your code... same error... func.call is not a function.

Comment: It's calling the function now.  Preciate it!